# What is recommended casing for export a React context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen in some blog posts `SpeakerConstant` instead of what I think is corrrect `speakerContext` in the example below.  My thinking is that `const speakerContext` is a local and it gets exported so it should be lower as in the example below.

Am I correct? Is the below the right casing for the const speakerContext?

```
import React from "react";

const speakerContext = React.createContext({
  speakers: []
});

export default speakerContext;
```

Comment: I don't think it matters because you are exporting it as default

Comment: curios why this has a vote down? I thought out the question, I provided an example, I gave my reasoning. Seems like a not obvious answer based on the proposed answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not if you were to consult the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), it promotes the use of Pascal casing for context objects, which if you look at the usage of them would make sense. They have a "type" feel about them, almost like a static class, and they are consumed as such e.g.

```
<SpeakerContext.Provider>...</SpeakerContext.Povider>
...
contextType: SpeakerContext
```

I don't think the above reads well in camel casing. Having said that, there are no rules dictating this *has* to be the way, it's just *a* way that the creators of React suggest you use.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter at all, don't get caught up in irrelevant things. This is what my file that imports yours could look like:

```
import something from './speakerContext';

const { Provider } = something;

const MyComponent = () => <Provider value={somevalue}>{children}</Provider>
```

Do what works for you.